# deserialize then serialize json with dynamic field name

Tags: c#, json, oop, json.net, api-design

I have a JSON file that looks something like this.

```
{
  "id": "top1",
  "components": [
    {
      "type": "resistor",
      "id": "res1",
      "resistance": {
        "default": 100,
        "min": 10,
        "max": 1000
      },
      "netlist": {
        "t1": "vdd",
        "t2": "n1"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "nmos",
      "id": "m1",
      "m(l)": {
        "default": 1.5,
        "min": 1,
        "max": 2
      },
      "netlist": {
        "drain": "n1",
        "gate": "vin",
        "source": "vss"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to make an API using oop to work with that JSON file,
I made the following classes.

```
public class Topology
    {
        [Required]
        public string id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public List<TopologyComponents> components { get; set; }
    }
```

```
public class TopologyComponents
    {
        [Required]
        public string type { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public Values ???????? {get; set; }
        [Required]
        public Dictionary<string, string> netlist { get; set; }
    }
```

```
public class Values
    {
        [Required]
        public double @default { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public double min { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public double max { get; set; }
    }
```

my question is those question marks????????
the field name is dynamic `resistance, m(l), .....`
how can I handle those cases?
I tried Jackson annotations, expandobject, and dictionaries. but none of them worked as I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the looks of it, your `Topology` class will need to have `Dictionary<string, dynamic>` data type since the keys of `components` will be arbitrary. Even though `type` and `id` will be the same across all components, `netlist` and one other property will be dynamic.

Change your list of components to `Dictionary<string, dynamic>` and then get the data you need by first checking which property actually exists in the component.

```
public class Topology
{
    [Required]
    public string id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public List<Dictionary<string, dynamic>> components { get; set; }
}
```

this will give you a list of dictionary with string as the keys and dynamic objects as the values. You can iterate through the keys using foreach loop on `components.Keys` and perhaps a switch statement to see if the key you expect exists when iterating through each component.

Example on how you can create your own list of components... not sure how you are going to use the data since that will drive the way you deserialize this,

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Topology>(jsonText);
List<dynamic> allComps = new List<dynamic>();
foreach(var component in obj.components)
{
    var comp = new ExpandoObject() as IDictionary<string, object>;
    foreach(var key in component.Keys)
    {
        switch (key)
        {
            case "id":
            case "type":
                comp.Add(key, component[key].ToString());
                break;

            case "netlist":
                comp.Add(key, component[key].ToObject<Dictionary<string, string>>());
                break;

            default:
                comp.Add(key, component[key].ToObject<Values>());
                break;
        }
    }
    allComps.Add(comp);
}
```

Comment: can you please elaborate a bit, I can't get it to work for me.

Comment: @AloneTheGreat added the block of code for your Topology class.

Comment: it results in [Link](https://justpaste.it/8kdz3)

Comment: @AloneTheGreat see edit in my post for a way to get the components